# gcc warning: incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

In my code I have:

```
char DRAW_EX[DRAW_HEIGHT][DRAW_WIDTH] = {
        "*     *",
        " *   * ",
        "   *   ",
        " *   * ",
        "*     *"
           };
char DRAW_CIRCLE[DRAW_HEIGHT][DRAW_WIDTH] = {
        "  ***  ",
        " *   * ",
        "*     *",
        " *   * ",
        "  ***  "
           };
char DRAW_EMPTY[DRAW_HEIGHT][DRAW_WIDTH] = {
        "       ",
        "       ",
        "       ",
        "       ",
        "       "
           };
```

And the line that gives me the warning is:

```
char** leftDraw;
leftDraw = board[i][0]==EMPTY?DRAW_EMPTY:(board[i][0]==SHAPE_O?DRAW_CIRCLE:DRAW_EX);
```

The warning is:

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pointers are not arrays. They're two distinct types. You can't pretend one is the other.

Comment: Why not supply code that reproduces the problem (where is `board` declared`) etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are trying to assign a `char (*)[DRAW_WIDTH]` to a `char**`. These are incompatible types.

Declare

```
char (*leftDraw)[DRAW_WIDTH];
```

and the compiler will be happy with that line.